# how to parse ODataQuery /ODataQueryOptions in endpoints that supports OData queries

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using net core 3.1., my project contains api controller(ODataController) that supports endpoints that OData queries.
I would like to parse OData queries in order to create a custom request to pass some other rest service.
How can i create a parser for OData queries ?

some endpoints that supports OData queries.

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()

[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute]
[EnableQuery(HandleNullPropagation = HandleNullPropagationOption.False, MaxTop = 100, 
AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.Select |AllowedQueryOptions.Count)]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Getlist(ODataQueryOptions options)
```

Comment: all information is stored in `ODataQueryOptions options` what do you mean by writing a parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could just break it down into its constituent parts:

```cs
ApplyClause applyClause = options.Apply.ApplyClause;
bool count = options.Count.Value;
FilterClause filterClause = options.Filter.FilterClause;
OrderByClause orderByClause = options.OrderBy.OrderByClause;
int skip = options.Skip.Value;
int top = options.Top.Value;
⋮
```

Or to get the `string` versions:

```cs
string applyClause = options.RawValues.Apply;
string count = options.RawValues.Count;
string filterClause = options.RawValues.Filter;
string orderByClause = options.RawValues.OrderBy;
string skip = options.RawValues.Skip;
string top = options.RawValues.Top;
⋮
```